# Can White get a theoretical advantage against the Sveshnikov Sicilian in today's theory?

Tags: opening, theory, sicilian-defense, sveshnikov

I'm looking for an opening expert or an experienced Sveshnikov player that knows the answer to this.

The Sveshnikov has been increasingly popular and it has also proven to be very good for draws. However, is there a line that like grants an unclear line that will give White a chance to fight for an advantage?

Also which line is considered better for avoiding a draw, the Bxf6 first line or the Nd5 line?

Comment: It is never just a line, but a huge tree of lines. The old main line killed by 22.Kf1!! in the Bxf6 Bxf6 Sveshnikov is good place to start. Still a lot of people will go to almost certain dead here, if you prepare well.

Comment: Look at Giri-Shirov 2014 if you don't know what line I mean. It is move number 1 in book on every move since Nd5 and it ends in huge trouble for black. In my source there were played another 4 games, all correspondence, and all were won by white. That tells everything.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting data. P.s. Glorfindel, what did you edit on my post? Lol. I don't see any changes? Edit: Oh the title was improved, and you added 2 additional tags. Thank you!

Comment: @SorinSolberg I only edited the tags. You can click on the [edited x hours ago](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/18207/revisions) link above my 'user card'.

Comment: I think the main reason why we don't see many Svechnikovs anymore is because in the 9.Bxf6 and 10.c4 line Black gets a boring position with no chance to play for a win, even if White's advantage (if any) is not huge and a good defense will yield a draw.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your second question first: According to chesstempo db there are 6% less draws after 9.Bxf6 than after 9.Nd5, with White and Black each getting 3% more wins!
As far as a theoretical advantage: hoacin's comment is accurate.  Of course like all openings it is more about heading to the positions you like or are more comfortable with; thus many GMs would say that 3.Bb5 is the best move against the Sveshnikov.